# in SQL Add months and retain lowest day in the span

Tags: sql, datetime, addition

I am writing a Query to correct some bad data. We have a date "DueDate" and every month we add one month to that date with date add. so 1/30 becomes 2/28, then after that it is 3/28, and 4/28 and so on.

I am trying to write a query where I can add x months to an original DueDate, but treat it like it is iterating through each month individually. So in effect, 1/30 +2 Months should be 3/28, because it had to go through February.

I want to be able to do the calculation in a single update for the whole data set to keep it clean and simple.

Examples of how I want it to calculate

1/30 +2 months -> 3/28 (because it goes through Feb 28 and never goes back up)

5/31 +5 months -> 10/30 (because it goes through Jun 30 and never goes back up)

Comment: Tag the desired RDMS

Comment: You need to give some example input and example output because you question is not clear.

Comment: What is an RDMS?

Comment: Example,
1/30 +2 Months gives 3/30, I want it to be:
1/30 +2 Months gives 3/28 because what I want to mimic is 1/30 +1 month, 2/28, then +1 month to that, so 3/28

Another example

Comment: [Wikipedia on RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

Using a Calendar table and [**`count() over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to get the latest date where that day occurs in each month:

```
declare @FromDate date = '20160130';
declare @ThruDate date = '20161231';
set @FromDate = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@FromDate),0);
/* Calendar Table substitue for demo*/
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, d as (
  select DateValue=convert(date,dateadd(day
      , row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate))
  from         n as deka cross join n as hecto
    cross join n as kilo cross join n as [10k]
)
, cal as (
  select top (datediff(day, @FromDate, @ThruDate)+1)
      [Date] = DateValue
    , [Day]  = convert(tinyint,datepart(day,DateValue)) 
  from d
  order by DateValue
)
/* query */
select top 1 [date]
from (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by day) as dm_count
  from cal 
  ) s
where dm_count = datediff(month,@fromdate,@thrudate)+1
order by [date] desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TZROKS25405

returns:

```
+------------+
|    date    |
+------------+
| 2016-12-29 |
+------------+
```

> Note: 2016 was a leap year, so there were 29 days in February.

calendar and numbers tables reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops 2- Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)